# Limits: Removing indeterminate form of the type $∞ \cdot 0$.

Tags: limits

During solving a question, I encountered an limit,

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{1 + n \sin^2 x}$$
I have to find value of this limit when $x\to 0$ from right and $n$ tends to $∞$.
The answer given is zero.
I have tried many ways to remove indeterminate form but I failed to remove it. Please help me to solve this limit.

(it is not an homework question).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "limit when $x$ tends to 0 from right and $n$ tends to $\infty$".  Perhaps the problem is $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{1 + n \sin^2 x}$?  That would mean that, for fixed $x > 0$, you find the limit as $n$ tends to $\infty$, and then you take the limit of _that_ answer as $x$ tends to 0 from the right.

Comment: In the linked question $x$ is not said to approach anything, certainly not zero. Did you clip off a part of the question when you made the photo?

Comment: If $x$ is small and nonzero, then $\sin^2 x$ is strictly positive, so $\lim_{n \to \infty}(1 + n\sin^2 x) \to \infty$, hence the reciprocal converges to zero. Since this is true for any small nonzero $x$, then the limit as $x \to 0$ is also zero.

Comment: @Dan Velleman. Yes , that's my question.

Comment: @coffeemath. Yes.

Comment: I think it's counterproductive to call this an "$\infty\cdot 0$ indeterminate form", which has a specific meaning for some other situation. This is simply an iterated limit, and as Bungo comments, the inner limit is easy enough to evaluate that the double limit becomes trivial.

Comment: @TheExplorer: As Greg mentions above, this is not a "$0 \cdot \infty$" indeterminate form. That's when you have two functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f(x)\to \infty$ and $g(x)\to0$ as $x\to a$, and you are asked to compute $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)g(x)$. This limit is said to be indeterminate because, without further information about what $f$ and $g$ are, this limit is impossible to evaluate.

Answer (score 2):

To evaluate
$$
\lim_{x \to 0^+}\left(\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{1 + n \sin^2 x}\right) \, ,
$$
you to have a clear understanding of what the above expression means. It's not that $x$ and $n$ are both approaching $0$ and $\infty$ respectively "at the same time" or anything like that. The expression inside the brackets is just a function like any other, and you are being asked to evaluate the behaviour of a function around $0$. Let
$$
f(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{1+n\sin^2x} \, .
$$
If $x$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$,
$$
f(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{1}=1 \, .
$$
If $x$ is not an integer multiple of $\pi$, then $g(n)=(\sin^2x)n+1$ is a linear function with a positive gradient, and so $g(n)\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. Hence,
$$
f(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{1+n\sin^2x}=0 \, .
$$
Therefore,
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1 &\text{if $x$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$.} \\
0 &\text{if $x$ is not an integer multiple of $\pi$.}
\end{cases}
$$
We are asked to evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0^+}f(x)$. When computing limits, we only care about the behaviour of a function near the limit point, not *at* the limit point. Since $f(x)$ is identically equal to $0$ for all $x\in\left(0,\pi\right)$, we get that $\lim_{x \to 0^+}f(x)=0$. Indeed, we have the stronger result that $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)=0$.

Comment: "$x\ne 0$" should be "$x$ is not a multiple of $\pi$" ...

Comment: @Troposphere: Thanks, I think I've fixed it. Please let me know if there is still something wrong.

Comment: Now I think "for all $x\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$" needs to exclude $x=0$. Or perhaps just say $(0,\pi)$ instead, since the OP is (for whatever reason) interested in a one-sided limit anyway.

Comment: @Troposphere: I've changed it to "for all $x\in(0,\pi)$. Thanks again. I'm scanning my answer carefully to make it sure it doesn't contain any more silly mistakes!